# C Program stuck/hanging on pthread_join

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, web-crawler

Context: I've built a multi-threaded program that uses some mutexes and a semaphore to handle synchronization (attached below). The purpose of the program is to crawl the web from a seed URL until it's either exhausted all options from the seed URL or has found m valid PNG files (m is user-specified or 50 by default).

Problem: The program hangs right before the threads join when m ≥ 50, even though 50 PNGs have been found. Forcing an `exit(0);` call causes the program to terminate but it doesn't print out execution time which follows `pthread_join()` statements in main. When calling `pthread_exit()` instead of join, the program just hangs for values of m ≥ 50, but it terminates fine when m < 50.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
      struct timeval starting_time;
      gettimeofday(&starting_time, NULL);

      get_opts(argc, argv);
      hcreate(1500);
      curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
      struct Queue* queue = createQueue(200);

      /* enqueuing the first url to explore */
      enqueue(queue, seed_url);
      ENTRY e;
      e.key = seed_url;

      /* don't need a mutex here */
      hsearch(e, ENTER);
      pthread_t ptids[t];

      /* initialize various semaphores and mutexes */
      pthread_mutex_init(&m_mutex, NULL);
      pthread_mutex_init(&frontier_mutex, NULL);
      pthread_mutex_init(&visited_mutex, NULL);
      pthread_mutex_init(&log_mutex, NULL);

      /* initializing to 1 bc of the seed url */
      sem_init(&filled, 0, 1);

      for(int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
          pthread_create(&ptids[i], NULL, crawl, queue);
      }

      for(int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
         printf("waiting to join\n");
         pthread_join(ptids[i], NULL);
      }

      destroyQueue(queue);
      sem_destroy(&filled);
      pthread_mutex_destroy(&m_mutex);
      pthread_mutex_destroy(&frontier_mutex);
      pthread_mutex_destroy(&visited_mutex);
      pthread_mutex_destroy(&log_mutex);
      hdestroy();

       /* calculate running time */
      struct timeval ending_time;
      gettimeofday(&ending_time, NULL);
      double running_time = calculate_running_time(starting_time, ending_time);
      printf("findpng2 execution time: %f seconds\n", running_time);

      return 0;
  }

void* crawl(void * args) {
      struct Queue* queue = (struct Queue *) args;
      while(m > 0) {
          CURL *curl_handle;
          CURLcode res;
          unsigned char *url = (unsigned char *) malloc(250 * sizeof(char));
          RECV_BUF recv_buf;
          sem_wait(&filled);
          pthread_mutex_lock(&frontier_mutex);
          if (isEmpty(queue)) {
              pthread_mutex_unlock(&frontier_mutex);
              pthread_exit(NULL);
          }
          // check frontiers with mutex and take first frontier
          dequeue(queue, url);
          if (v) {
              log(url);
          }
          pthread_mutex_unlock(&frontier_mutex);
          curl_handle = easy_handle_init(&recv_buf, url);

          if ( curl_handle == NULL ) {
              fprintf(stderr, "Curl initialization failed. Exiting...\n");
              curl_global_cleanup();
              abort();
          }
          /* get it! */
          res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
          if (res == CURLE_OK) {
              process_data(curl_handle, &recv_buf, NULL, queue);
          }
          recv_buf_cleanup(&recv_buf);
      }
      pthread_exit(NULL);
  }
```

When killing the program in gdb, and running `backtrace full`, I get:

```
Thread 1 "findpng2" received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff757cd2d in __GI___pthread_timedjoin_ex (threadid=140737201288960,
    thread_return=0x0, abstime=0x0, block=<optimized out>)
    at pthread_join_common.c:89
89  pthread_join_common.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace full
#0  0x00007ffff757cd2d in __GI___pthread_timedjoin_ex (
    threadid=140737201288960, thread_return=0x0, abstime=0x0,
    block=<optimized out>) at pthread_join_common.c:89
        __tid = 25642
        _buffer = {__routine = 0x7ffff757cb90 <cleanup>,
          __arg = 0x7fffeee3bd28, __canceltype = 15, __prev = 0x0}
        oldtype = 0
        pd = 0x7fffeee3b700
        self = <optimized out>
        result = 0
#1  0x0000555555555d1f in main (argc=4, argv=0x7fffffffeaa8) at findpng2.c:74
        i = 0
        starting_time = {tv_sec = 1605405493, tv_usec = 186323}
        queue = 0x5555557aaad0
        e = {key = 0x7fffffffed3d "http://ece252-1.uwaterloo.ca/lab4/",
          data = 0x7fffffffe9a8}
        ptids = {140737201288960, 140737192896256, 140737176110848,
          140737167718144, 140736951482112, 140736943089408, 140736934696704,
          140736926304000, 140736917911296, 140736909518592}
        ending_time = {tv_sec = 140737488349604, tv_usec = 140737488349600}
        running_time = 6.9533462138242249e-310
```

which I find quite interesting, since the variable names after pthread_join have been populated.

Comment: Sounds like at least one thread doesn't exit on its own.

Comment: Just a note that there are additional methods, i.e. `process_png` that decrements the counter m, which I can confirm is equal to 0 when the program hangs. I can happily add that code, I didn't originally because I didn't want to make the question too noisy and I don't *think* the other methods are causing the issue.

Comment: @Shawn yup, that sounds about right. Any way I can force some threads to exit if others already have? And any idea as to why they're not exiting on their own? Only thing I can think of is potential deadlock, but helgrind doesn't lead me to believe that's the case.

Comment: At a minimum get the stack trace of the threads that have not exited. Your code is incomplete so we don't know whether the threads could be blocked on any of the other mutexes.

Comment: 1.  Those variables haven't been populated; look at the tv_usec field; does that make sense?  2.  your reliance on the hidden `m` is suspicious since you access it without holding any sort of synchronization object.  That *implies* that you could be accessing and making decisions on stale values of it.